# return the row where before and after value is lower

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, where-clause

I have a table that looks like this:

```
name         val
1            1
2            2
3            1
4            2
5            2
6            10
```

For each row, I want to check if there's an increase in the value as compared to the last value. Then, I want to return the rows where the previous and next value is lower. For example, in this case, I want to return

```
name         val
2            2
```

but not any of the following:

```
4            2
5            2
6            10
```

since there's a constant increase till the end of the table and no decrease at the end. Ideally, I would also like to order the table by the `name`col before I start comparing the `val`.

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-lag-function/     https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-lead-function/

Comment: (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)(4,3),(5,1) - what is the expected result?

Comment: expected result is ```2,2```@Serg

Comment: Not sure I understand the rule.  Why (4,3) doesn't satisfy the condition "where before and after value is lower" ?

Comment: the before value isn't lower for (4,3). 3 stays 3. in (3,3) and (4,3). @Serg

Comment: For (2,2) the next value (3,3)  is not lower .  Looks like it doesn't match the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write a query using lead and lag functions like below

Explanation:

So lag gets data for Val column from preceding row and lead gets from next row

We add a case statement to handle null values for first row's lag and last row's lead data.
To know more about the lead lag functions read up on this [link](https://postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/%E2%80%A6)

```
select name, val 
from 
(select *,
 CASE WHEN LAG(val) OVER( ORDER BY name) IS NULL THEN 
val ELSE LAG(val) OVER( ORDER BY name) END as prev_value,
    CASE WHEN LEAD(val)  OVER( ORDER BY name) IS NULL THEN val ELSE LEAD(val)  OVER( ORDER BY name) END as next_value
    from yourtable 
    )T
    where prev_value<val AND val> next_value
```

Using default values

```
select name, val 
from 
(select *,
 LAG(val,1,val) OVER( ORDER BY name) as prev_value,
 LEAD(val,1,val) OVER( ORDER BY name) as next_value
    from yourtable 
    )T
    where prev_value<val AND val> next_value
```

Comment: Could you also explain this a bit?

Comment: @Jbd, Note it will return nothing for the (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)(4,3),(5,1)  input.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Hello that case could be replace using the third argument in lead and lag as lag(val,1,val)over.... or just coalesce.

Comment: @Florin could you add another answer with your method?

Comment: @Jbd I've added to answer